# Creating an user experience roadmap?

Tags: design-process, product-management

I was asked today if we could create an user experience roadmap for the application we are designing. I am a little confused about that since I have never really heard of the term user experience roadmap and I suspect its the same as a product roadmap but I am pretty sure there are some differences.

Any inputs on what would go into such a roadmap and how it would differ from a product roadmap would be great.

Comment: I would bet that it is the same as a product roadmap, but for UX activities -- and that can be a really good thing -- but before answering that way, do you know if the term "product roadmap" is used in your organization as a synonym for "general plan for development" like @DA01 describes, or one significantly [more detailed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_roadmap)?

Comment: I've seen quite a few diagrams over the past few days concerning ux strategies and roadmaps. I'd love to see some of your results since this question is a little older. Would you mind?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I despise roadmaps. From my experience, they seem to consist of:

- we will design this part now
- this part later
- then this part then

And if it's coming strictly from UX, it really doesn't make sense in a broader team POV.

Instead, I'd like to see a list of must-have priorities, followed by nice-to-have, and then maybe we'll do these if we have time...

So, all that said, I don't think it matters what we think the specifics of a road map are, but rather what your team(s) need/want.

If this is a development team and they're asking for guidance as to what to work on first, I'd suggest that's not the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

When a product owner says "show me a ux roadmap" you respond back "show me yours and i'll show you mine" meaning, show me your product management roadmap. As you first need to be careful here you're **NOT** doing his/her homework for them (some will game you, as it's easy to avoid having to do an introspective look at ones existing legacy product line).

I've created a few UX Roadmaps and typically these have been at a product portfolio level. My goal really is to surface the momentum the products are driving at in terms of how the technology landscape and program of ux initiatives i've been running are "dropping" in a typical roadmappy timeline.

Things like - "ProductXYZ goes live with Android/iPhone Q1" "ProductXYZ goes live with Surface3 Q2" "PSAT / NSAT health indexes results in Q1" " Ux Bootcamps and vNext workshops Q3" etc etc..

Its in my case a slide or two that helps Product Managers or Program Managers figure out how they can line up their bets to fit in with mine or look for ways to figure out how they are faring in their own product lines to help determine how far ahead or behind they are in their investment of whatever Ux initiative is underway.